# How expensive is the structural materials on a stealth aircraft compared to its other components?

Tags: aircraft-design, stealth

Well, I couldn't find much information about the prices on the materials used on stealth aircraft, but nevertheless, its huge price tags are often quite obvious. The B-2 bomber, for example, costs 2 billion dollars.

But of course, these aircraft aren't just its radar signal absorbent composite materials, but its engines, its electronics and so on.

At first, I always thought that the radar signal absorbent materials where the most expensive parts, since no other conventional aircraft used them. But just to be sure, they are as costly as their other components, or they are as cheaper than conventional materials?

Comment: These types of costs, as well as the details of the materials themselves, are simply not made public until many years after production, for very good reasons. Plus the technology is not just "radar absorbent" - there are incredible things done with special shapes that reflect radar in a particular way. End result, my understanding (but not an expert, so just a comment) is that very, very few people outside key people in the manufacturers and a relatively small group (much smaller than "all of Congress") of government employees know this stuff. And are sworn to not tell anyone else.

Comment: Stealth aircraft are conventional aircraft with airframe shapes and surface coatings designed to minimize radar return and dissipate/mask infrared heat signatures. In some cases flight control systems are different because the designs are aerodynamically unstable and require computerized fly-by-wire to control them in-flight. Their structural materials are not much different than other aircraft though.